# How to load dark theme without an delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I am creating a webpage with dark-mode theme feature. I got my bundle.css where I have defined dark-mode class. I am using a javascript onclick event to set the cookie value and if the value is true after reload, javascript will generate class on the body element. However, if I reload the page, initially style will be loaded firstly so I can see the white background (light theme) for a few milliseconds and then the dark theme is loaded. And this delay is an *issue*.

I have also tried to add my JavaScript into the head, however, it did not solve the issue. I am using webpack in this project. Css, js and html files are divided into modules.

**My question is:**
Is there any solution or way to load dark theme quickly without this delay or white blinking background by using javascript? Or backend is needed here? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You can make the page stay in loading state until you read the cookie value, perhaps.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz This is something what I am trying to avoid. Because I'm creating a site for a local newspaper, and long loading or any loading animation is something what they actually do not want to hear about. This web [link](https://www.macstories.net/) is a good example of a darkmode I am trying to create. However, the javascript they have in the head seems to be incomplete.

Comment: A pretty loader could help you for the interval in which your styles changes

Comment: without delay = server setting value.

Comment: `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

}`

Answer (score 0):

I think, the way to go is to replace the css file before it is loaded, I use the smarty template engine and create a variable which replaces the css path. Only problem is you need to reload once if you change the theme, so no instant color-swap.

Comment: Thank for the tip! Your suggestion actually helped me more than most of the internet :D Maybe I just needed to kick my mind.

I created another bundle.css with dark-mode values and then created a short javascript that will check the cookie and according to the cookie it does disable or enable stylesheet. Reload is needed, but it is not a problem, especially in case, there is no delay and dark-mode is loaded directly. Thank again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my way of handling dark-mode a bit: I still use a template engine which has a template for a page without content. The template engine excecutes a php script before displaying the website itself, so I check for dark mode first, then if it is enabled (e.g. a Cookie is set), I add the **dark** class to the **body** while displaying the html (So no delay). So every css class you want to change can be addressed like

```
body.dark .text1 
{
   color: #fffff;
}
```

so it will override the color of .text1. Using **body.dark** also allows you to instantly change the theme without reloading the page and with no delay. You can add and remove the **dark** class on the fly with JS and every class with **body.dark** as a prefix will change when you add the **dark** class to the **body** of the website. If you want to see a more detailed example, feel free to ask.